# Array of objects: accessing an object's value without iterating through the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of similarly structured objects:

```
var my_arr = [{property1: some_value, property2: another_value}, {}, {}, ...];
```

Currently, to find the object containing a target value, I iterate through each element of the array:

```
var my_obj, target_value;
    for (let obj_in_arr of my_arr) {
        if (obj_in_arr.property1 === target_value) {
            my_obj = obj_in_arr;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is there a faster way? How can I access the object with the target value directly, without resorting to iteration?

Comment: *"How can I access the object with the target value"* Which object? there are dozens. If you know the index of the object, sure that's possible. Otherwise, no, you have to iterate.

Comment: If you've got a set of objects in a data structure like an array, then finding one particular object will *always* involve iteration. That's just the nature of the beast. If you need more direct access, create a `Map` instance or a plain object that maps string keys to particular array elements.

Comment: If you only know your target value, then you have to iterate the array at least partially to find the object with that target (as you currently are). Unless you somehow know which index the object with that target value is at beforehand, afaik there is no way to avoid iteration. Maybe consider creating an index object that maps target values to indices?

Comment: This depends on the use case, but if you are planning to repeatedly search for elements, you can prepopulate a map. There's an upfront cost of building it, but after that searches are "instant", aka O(1)

Comment: Thank you, all. Pointy and Andrew, it sounds like prepopulating a Map fits my purposes best, so thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prepopulate a `new Map` all subsequent searches will be in O(1)

```
const objMap = new Map()
for (let obj of my_arr) {
  objMap.set(obj.property1, obj)
}

function getObject(target, map) {
  return map.get(target)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. What's O(1)? (Novice programmer here...)

Comment: Big O notation represents time complexity of a function. It represents the number of operations it takes you code to go from start to end. It is assumed to be worst case scenario. O(n) is iterating across the entire array, because each element must be observed, where `n` represents the number of array elements. O(1) is the best possible time complexity. It represents a single operation. Common O(1) processes are getting an array value by its index, math operations, searching for a key in objects and maps, and searching for values in a set.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to iterate the array anyway, but you can try _.findIndex of underscore.js

http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to find a value once, then iteration is really the only way.

If you will want to find many values in the array, you could create an object keyed on your target property to serve as a lookup table:

```
var lookup = {};

for (var i = 0; i < my_arr.length; i++) {
    lookup[my_arr[i].property1] = my_arr[i];
}
```

That front loads some work, but could save you time ultimately if you have many lookups to make.

Lookups would be as simple as:

```
my_obj = lookup[target_value];
```

If you have access to es2015 you could make your lookup table generation a little more concise:

```
const lookup = my_arr.reduce((m, v) => (m[v.property1] = v, m), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

this will still iterate through the array but you could use the native js find function.

```
const objArray = [{ val: 1}, { val: 2}];
const targetObj = objArray.find((obj) => obj.val == 2 ) // { val: 2}
```